# libsndfile always segfaults when using sf_open_fd()

Tags: c++, memory, stream, libsndfile

I am trying to stream audio for an application I am building but I have run into a snag with a library I am using. This library is libSndFile. The library always has a SEGFAULT whenever I call `sf_open_fd(int fd, int mode, SF_INFO *info, int close_desc);` I am using this function instead of `sf_open(const char *path, int mode, SF_INFO *info)` because I need to have libSndFile decode data that is in a buffer in memory. I couldn't make sense of the `sf_virtual_open()` documentation, so I am using this instead. I can get a valid file descriptor using fileno() (it returns 14 usually) and my FILE stream is valid, so it is just this function. I don't know where it might be SEGFAULTing or on what. Is there a better way for me to have libSndFile decode a memory buffer or am I not using something right?

Here is the problem code (I have added some comments to have it make more sense)

```
memset(&/*SF_INFO*/mInfo, 0, sizeof(SF_INFO));

/* FILE* */mpFileStream = tmpfile();

fwrite(/* void* */aBuffer, /*int*/aSize, 1, mpFileStream);

int iDescriptor = fileno(mpFileStream);

if(iDescriptor == -1)
{
    return /*enum EError*/EError_Unknown;
}

/* SNDFILE* */mFile = sf_open_fd(iDescriptor, SFM_READ, mInfo, SF_TRUE);

return mFile != NULL ? /*enum EError*/EError_None : /*enum EError*/EError_Unknown;
```

I really prefer to not be writing to the disk, but I had to to get a valid file descriptor and stream.

NOTE: I am compiling on Xubuntu 12.04 with g++ 4.6.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably on the first line:

memset(&/*SF_INFO*/mInfo, 0, sizeof(SF_INFO));

You're calling sf_open_fd() later using mInfo as a pointer parameter, so I'm guessing mInfo is actually a SF_INFO* rather than an SF_INFO. memset() allows any pointer type so you don't get a compile error.

Incidentally, you shouldn't need to write to the disk - tmpfile() returns an opened file that should work with fileno().

Edit: Actually rereading your question I may have misunderstood when you said you didn't know where the SEGFAULT is occurring. One thing I found in the libsndfile docs is that sf_open_fd() can't be used if your program is linked against a different runtime than the library. That might be the problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to specify my OS, I'm on Linux (Xubuntu 12.04) and I will change the memset line because in looking at the code, that doesn't seem right now. So I'll keep playing with it till something works (hopefully) and thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Well, no more SEGFAULT! Thank you very much!

Comment: @HerrJoebob The problem with different runtimes is really only an issue on Windows. I've never seen it or heard of this problem on Linux or OS X.